# how do I add a button to the bottom of a color box

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I am new to colorbox. I want to add a button to my color box (because I want to replace the X button in color box with a button that says "closed"). Following [this tutorial](http://www.blackbam.at/blackbams-blog/2013/07/02/how-to-add-social-media-buttons-to-jquery-colorbox/) (I don't want social media buttons, just a simple "close" button), I wrote/tried the following code. But it is not adding the button the color box. What am I missing?

```
var myButtonVar = '<div id="myButton">Button Text</div>';
jQuery("#cboxContent").append('<div id="buttons">' + myButtonVar +'</div>'); 

$.colorbox({width:"30%", inline:true, href:"#inline_content",
    onClosed: function() {
        alert("closing");
    },
});
```

Comment: general sense, look like your color box has not refer anything with your button. my thoughts: if #cboxContent come after $.colorbox code, you should put you append code after $.colorbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "x" IS a button that says "close" -- it simply has some CSS styling that shrinks it, indents the text to make it invisible, and adds a background image.  You can undo these things, and add a little styling, with the following CSS:

```
#cboxClose {
    background: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 15px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

If you have a grouped colorbox, then the arrows will get in the way of your newly-styled button, so you'll have to scoot them to the left like this:

```
#cboxPrevious {
    right: 64px;
}
#cboxPrevious {
    right: 42px;
}
```

And if you have a slide show you may want to scoot the play/pause button too:

```
#cboxSlideshow {
    right: 84px;
}
```